# "New" button missing from Connected Apps

Tags: connected-apps

I'm reading through the [Force.com Canvas Developer's Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/canvas_framework.pdf) and on page #17, I see the following instructions:

```
 1. In Salesforce, from Setup, enter Apps in the Quick Find box, then select Apps.
 2. In the Connected Apps related list, click New.
 ...
```

However, I don't see a "New" button in the Connected Apps list:

[image]

I have checked to ensure that I have "Customize Application" and "Modify All Data" permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Easy cookie :)

you are looking under Manage Apps. The doc says look for Apps, if you search in the quick find you should see Apps under the create menu

Go to setup --> Create --> Apps --> Connected Apps

you can create new connected app from here :)

Answer (score 3):

Anyone looking for this in Lightning - search for "App Manager" in the setup quick-find. Then hit the "New Connected App" button.

[image]